# Secure TCP connection for LAN-only connections

Tags: security, ssl, networking, tcp, lan

I'm working on network program intended for (W)LAN-only applications. The program is going to exchange data over TCP. I want to introduce at least some level of security, therefore I'm thinking about securing raw TCP connections anonymous TLS.

I'm aware, that anonymous TLS has well-know vulnerabilities (man in the middle), but I cannot enforce (W)LAN members to obtain certificates and I'll have no authentication. As I understand anonymous TLS will ensure data integrity and encryption.

Do you think it's worth to play with TLS in my case? Maybe there's easier way to ensure data integrity and encryption?

Comment: I think this should be on the security SE. Flag for mods to move it.

Comment: IPSec in transport mode? Anonymous TLS will not ensure data integrity as a MITM could intercept the data and modify it by spoofing the destination and then forwarding traffic. Could you use an encrypted protocol such as HTTPS - you could authenticate clients by means of a key - authentication of the server will be done through TLS and PKI.

Comment: @SilverlightFox IPSec is possible solution, but it requires extra configuration. I'm rather looking for application-layer solution. HTTPS will incur to high overhead and require additional code for handling HTTP(S) in my application. Like I said, users may verbally share key, is there a well-know system that may take advantage of that?